# multi-module spring roo project setup

Tags: maven, spring-roo, multi-module

I am really new to Spring Roo (perhaps been using it for 2.5 months) and on the whole it has been a very good experience, and I have rapidly created a system for managing a property portfolio.

HOWEVER, this system was developed in three seperate roo projects:

Property Management - mongo backend

Accounts Management - mongo backend

Address Book - JPA

Now I am looking to combine them in one project, with one home page to access all three parts, I am aware of maven multi-module support which Is included in roo, but when I attempted to combine the three projects by creating a Spring Roo Multi Module Project, defining the three modules and then importing each of the three modules into their respective folders, on deployment only the first module to be reached in the compilation was setup and the path for localhost access was not the name of the multi-module project but the name of the project which was compiled..

Does anyone know any resources or have any tips for creating a multi module webapp from the combination of three existing webapps?

Thanks

Comment: See if the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12205890/spring-roo-multi-module-dependencies/12207434#12207434) helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just start with a folder structure like this:

```
 root (pom.xml) Aggregator
  +-- mod-mongo-property
  +-- mod-mongo-accounts
  +-- mod-jpa
```

Move all comming things like dependencies and plugins (in particular versions) into appropriate parent (depenendencyManager, pluginManagement).

Comment: So once I have the Aggregator project set up, I create the three modules and set up the persistence within them, do i then import the three projects? How does spring manage the views etc?